# split single project into a multiple project solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

We have a single project which we are going to split into a multiple project solution. we are going to take the Entities and put them in a new assembly

The current project has EF Core with ModelMetadata and other properties and methods.

```
namespace Project.Models.Entities
{
    [ModelMetadataType(typeof(ContactsMetaData))]
    public partial class Contacts
    {
        internal class ContactsMetaData
        {
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public string IsValid { get {return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email);} }

    }
}
```

Since the we cannot extend a partial class from a different assembly this will not work. I am looking for another solution to do this. I have tried to extend the class but it’s not working... 
Could anyone point me to a better solution?

Comment: Have u tried `Implements`?

Comment: @Joel: No, not sure how..

Comment: You can implement another class by using `:` syntax. Google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's more than one way to do it and you will have to make some design decisions.  I assume you want the repository assembly to only be concerned with accessing the database through entity framework.  But the business object needs additional properties like email address.  You can decouple the database objects from the domain object.  You could start with an interface that describes your contact entities.

```
public interface IContact
{
    // properties based on the Contacts you are working with
}
```

Then you could use a partial class in the repository assembly to state that `Contacts` implements the `IContact` interface.

```
public partial class Contacts : IContact
{

}
```

But you really need a contact with email, so describe that requirement with another interface.

```
public interface IContactWithEmail
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And inject the `IContact` dependency in the implementation.

```
public class ContactWithEmail : IContactWithEmail
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ContactWithEmail(IContact contact, string email)
    {
        FirstName = contact.FirstName;
        LastName = contact.LastName;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you miss here is the entire concept of inheritance.

Here you can find some usefull info about it and object oriented programming in general:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)